# scrape webpage without defined elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a very simple webpage in python.

Most directions that I find on scraping instruct you to look at the source to determine the structure, then to use "elements" to access the information that you need. The webpage that I am working with however is poorly formatted and doesn't have the types of elements described in examples online.

My webpage looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    "Title 1, Title 2, Title 3"
    <br>
    "Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"
    <br>
    "Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to read all of this into an excel file with each line of info as a new line, each piece of information in a different column. Any advice on how to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lxml` and `XPath`:

```
from lxml import html

HTML = """<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    "Title 1, Title 2, Title 3"
    <br>
    "Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"
    <br>
    "Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"
    <br>
  </body>
</html>"""

tree = html.fromstring(HTML)
results = [x.strip() for x in tree.xpath('//body/text()')]
print results
```

**Output:**

```
[
  '"Title 1, Title 2, Title 3"',
  '"Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"',
  '"Info 1, Info 2, Info 3"',
  ''
]
```

You can finally use `csv` library to write a CSV format file which you could open with Excel.

Answer (score -1):

I would start like that: Grab the entire `<body>` (i.e. take `<body>` as one of those *elements described in examples online*).

Then save the entire string as text file. (If you use `csv` as extension, you can open it with Excel right away.)

Open it in Excel. If you're lucky, the comma as treated as columns separator, and there you go! (Just need to get rid of those `<br>`'s, but that shouldn't be too big a problem).